# Remove Context Menu Items of Eclipse-Plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, contextmenu, menuitem

One of my eclipse plugins adds this context menu item:

```
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
    <menu id="sourceMenuId" label="%Source">
        <command
              commandId="org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.format"
              id="sourceFormat"
              style="push">
            <visibleWhen checkEnabled="true" />
        </command>
    </menu>
</menuContribution>
```

Is it possible to remove it in my own plugin.xml?

I couldnt find any options to override the visible state.

Comment: A plugin can use the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point to define activites that can suppress menus items.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the `checkEnabled` is just to indicate if the item should have any enablement/visibility evaluations carried out when that item is normally about to be displayed as part of the menu. In other words, should we check each time the menu is meant to be displayed to see if this item should be shown, or do we do it one time? You have this correctly set to `true` so that it will undergo evaluations.

However, you have nothing assessing if the item should be displayed or not.

You need something along these lines in your plugin.xml...

```
<command
        commandId="com.mycompany.project.doSomething"
        style="push"
        tooltip="Do Something">
    <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
        <test property="com.mycompany.project.isVisibleConditionSet"/>
    </visibleWhen>
</command>
```

...where you use a property tester to programmatically test if you should display the item or not.

You would define the property tester like this in your plugin.xml file within a `<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">` section...

```
<propertyTester
        class="com.mycompany.project.testers.IsVisibleConditionSet"
        id="com.mycompany.project.isVisibleConditionSet"
        namespace="com.mycompany.project"
        properties="isVisibleConditionSet"
        type="java.lang.Object"/>
```

...where you need a class in code that implements a `PropertyTester` and it should be named according to the class name in the above XML. For example...

```
package com.mycompany.project.testers;

import org.eclipse.core.expressions.PropertyTester;
// other imports here as required

public class IsVisibleConditionSet extends PropertyTester {
    static final String CONDITION_TESTER = "isVisibleConditionSet";

    @Override
    public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args, Object expectedValue) {
        if (CONDITION_TESTER.equals(property)) {
            return SomeOtherClass.shouldDisplayDoSomethingMenuItem();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter too much what you place in the above `if` block so long as it runs quickly so that menu display avoids delays. You can call any logic in your code here as long as it is in scope.